# Fetch data with promise in react.js. State is empty. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem when fetching data from a CSV File. Here is my Code:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            isLoading: false,
        };
        console.log(this.state.data) // Data is gone =(
    }

toCSV(response){
        let reader = response.body.getReader();
        let decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');

        return reader.read().then(function (result) {
            let data = decoder.decode(result.value);
            let results = Papa.parse(data);
            let rows = results.data;
            return rows;
        });
    }

componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        let dataNames;
            return fetch('url/someFile.csv')
            .then(response => this.toCSV(response))
            .then(data => console.log(data)) // Data is here
            .then(data => this.setState(
                { data: data, isLoading: false }
            ));
    }
```

**Output inside fetch**:

```
(3) […]
0: Array(4) [ "abc", " 1", "aha", … ]
1: Array(4) [ "def", "2", "test", … ]
2: Array(4) [ "ghi", "3", "something", … ]
length: 6
```

**Output in constructor**:

```
[]
length: 0
```

I do not understand why **this.state** is empty. I know that the promise is an asynchronous function but i thougth that **this.setState({ data: data, isLoading: false })** would set the data into **this.state.data** and that the promise is then fulfilled.

I found this solution here, but I could not solve the problem with this: [React: import csv file and parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416529/react-import-csv-file-and-parse)

I also tried to do it with a **JSON file** because I thought the problem was my **toCSV function**, but the result was the same....

```
fetchJSON() {
        fetch(`someJSONfile.json`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => console.log(response))
            .then(data =>
                this.setState({
                    data: data,
                    isLoading: false,
                })
            )
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
```

I hope one of you might have an idea. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: The constructor is called before `componentDidMount`. You are initializing `data` with an empty array and log it immediately... why did you expect to see values set in a completely different function called at a different moment in time?

Comment: Oh such a simple solution. That solved my problem. I put the console.log into the render function as Peter suggested and now the Data is there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructor will run only once. With React.Component the render() method will rerun on state change
check it:

```
render(){
 console.log(this.state);
 return <h1>Hello World</h1>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `.then` which doesn't have this data. The code below should work for you.

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        let dataNames;
            return fetch('url/someFile.csv')
            .then(response => this.toCSV(response))
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                this.setState({ data: data, isLoading: false })
            })
    }
```

also, console.log is not in the appropriate place, if you want to log things to check it out, it should be placed after the execution of setState.