# How to read and update a csv file in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to read data from an excel CSV file and display it on my react application. There are some libraries which only reads data but I want the user to update a specific line of it

This is my csv file :

```
Date,Fajr Begins,Fajr Jama‘ah,Sunrise,Zuhr Begins,Zuhr Jama‘ah,Asr Mithl 1,Asr Mithl 2,Asr Jama‘ah,Maghrib Begins,Maghrib Jama‘ah,Isha Begins,Isha Jama‘ah 
01/01/2020,6:26,6:56,8:03,12:09,12:45,1:46,2:17,2:45,4:05,4:10,5:42,7:15
02/01/2020,6:26,6:56,8:03,12:10,12:45,1:47,2:18,2:45,4:06,4:11,5:43,7:15
03/01/2020,6:26,6:56,8:03,12:10,12:45,1:48,2:19,2:45,4:07,4:12,5:44,7:15
04/01/2020,6:26,6:56,8:03,12:10,12:45,1:49,2:20,2:45,4:09,4:14,5:46,7:15
05/01/2020,6:25,6:55,8:02,12:11,12:25,1:50,2:21,2:45,4:10,4:15,5:47,7:15
06/01/2020,6:25,6:55,8:02,12:11,12:45,1:51,2:22,2:45,4:11,4:16,5:48,7:15
07/01/2020,6:25,6:55,8:02,12:12,12:45,1:52,2:23,2:45,4:12,4:17,5:49,7:15
08/01/2020,6:24,6:54,8:01,12:12,12:45,1:53,2:25,2:45,4:14,4:19,5:51,7:15
09/01/2020,6:24,6:54,8:01,12:13,12:45,1:55,2:26,2:45,4:15,4:20,5:52,7:15
10/01/2020,6:23,6:53,8:00,12:13,12:45,1:56,2:27,2:45,4:16,4:21,5:53,7:15
11/01/2020,6:22,6:52,7:59,12:13,12:45,1:57,2:29,2:45,4:18,4:23,5:55,7:15
12/01/2020,6:22,6:52,7:59,12:14,12:25,1:58,2:30,3:00,4:19,4:24,5:56,7:15
13/01/2020,6:21,6:51,7:58,12:14,12:45,1:59,2:31,3:00,4:21,4:26,5:58,7:15
14/01/2020,6:20,6:50,7:57,12:15,12:45,2:01,2:33,3:00,4:22,4:27,5:59,7:15
15/01/2020,6:19,6:49,7:56,12:15,12:45,2:02,2:34,3:00,4:24,4:29,6:01,7:15
16/01/2020,6:19,6:49,7:56,12:15,12:45,2:03,2:36,3:00,4:25,4:30,6:02,7:15
17/01/2020,6:18,6:48,7:55,12:16,12:45,2:04,2:37,3:00,4:27,4:32,6:04,7:15
18/01/2020,6:17,6:47,7:54,12:16,12:45,2:06,2:39,3:00,4:29,4:34,6:06,7:15
19/01/2020,6:16,6:46,7:53,12:16,12:25,2:07,2:40,3:00,4:30,4:35,6:07,7:15
20/01/2020,6:15,6:45,7:52,12:17,12:45,2:09,2:42,3:00,4:32,4:37,6:09,7:15
21/01/2020,6:14,6:44,7:51,12:17,12:45,2:10,2:44,3:00,4:34,4:39,6:11,7:15
22/01/2020,6:12,6:42,7:49,12:17,12:45,2:11,2:45,3:15,4:35,4:40,6:12,7:15
23/01/2020,6:11,6:41,7:48,12:17,12:45,2:13,2:47,3:15,4:37,4:42,6:14,7:15
24/01/2020,6:10,6:40,7:47,12:18,12:45,2:14,2:48,3:15,4:39,4:44,6:16,7:15
25/01/2020,6:09,6:39,7:46,12:18,12:45,2:16,2:50,3:15,4:40,4:45,6:17,7:15
26/01/2020,6:08,6:38,7:45,12:18,12:25,2:17,2:52,3:15,4:42,4:47,6:19,7:15
27/01/2020,6:06,6:36,7:43,12:18,12:45,2:18,2:53,3:15,4:44,4:49,6:21,7:15
28/01/2020,6:05,6:35,7:42,12:18,12:45,2:20,2:55,3:15,4:46,4:51,6:23,7:15
29/01/2020,6:03,6:33,7:40,12:19,12:45,2:21,2:57,3:15,4:47,4:52,6:24,7:15
30/01/2020,6:02,6:32,7:39,12:19,12:45,2:23,2:58,3:15,4:49,4:54,6:26,7:15
31/01/2020,6:00,6:30,7:37,12:19,12:45,2:24,3:00,3:15,4:51,4:56,6:28,7:15
01/02/2020,5:59,6:29,7:36,12:19,12:45,2:26,3:02,3:30,4:53,4:58,6:29,7:15
02/02/2020,5:57,6:27,7:34,12:19,12:25,2:27,3:04,3:30,4:55,5:00,6:30,7:15
03/02/2020,5:56,6:26,7:33,12:19,12:45,2:29,3:05,3:30,4:57,5:02,6:31,7:15
04/02/2020,5:54,6:24,7:31,12:19,12:45,2:30,3:07,3:30,4:58,5:03,6:32,7:15
05/02/2020,5:53,6:23,7:30,12:19,12:45,2:31,3:09,3:30,5:00,5:05,6:33,7:15
06/02/2020,5:51,6:21,7:28,12:20,12:45,2:33,3:10,3:30,5:02,5:07,6:35,7:15
07/02/2020,5:49,6:19,7:26,12:20,12:45,2:34,3:12,3:30,5:04,5:09,6:36,7:15
08/02/2020,5:47,6:17,7:24,12:20,12:45,2:36,3:14,3:45,5:06,5:11,6:38,7:15
09/02/2020,5:46,6:16,7:23,12:20,12:25,2:37,3:16,3:45,5:07,5:12,6:38,7:15
10/02/2020,5:44,6:14,7:21,12:20,12:45,2:39,3:17,3:45,5:09,5:14,6:40,7:15
11/02/2020,5:42,6:12,7:19,12:20,12:45,2:40,3:19,3:45,5:11,5:16,6:42,7:15
12/02/2020,5:40,6:10,7:17,12:20,12:45,2:41,3:21,3:45,5:13,5:18,6:44,7:15
13/02/2020,5:38,6:08,7:15,12:20,12:45,2:43,3:22,3:45,5:15,5:20,6:45,7:15
14/02/2020,5:36,6:06,7:13,12:20,12:45,2:44,3:24,3:45,5:17,5:22,6:47,7:15
15/02/2020,5:35,6:05,7:12,12:20,12:45,2:46,3:26,3:45,5:18,5:23,6:48,7:15
16/02/2020,5:33,6:03,7:10,12:20,12:25,2:47,3:27,3:45,5:20,5:25,6:50,7:15
17/02/2020,5:31,6:01,7:08,12:20,12:45,2:48,3:29,3:45,5:22,5:27,6:51,7:15
18/02/2020,5:29,5:59,7:06,12:19,12:45,2:50,3:31,3:45,5:24,5:29,6:53,7:15
19/02/2020,5:27,5:57,7:04,12:19,12:45,2:51,3:32,3:45,5:26,5:31,6:55,7:15
20/02/2020,5:25,5:55,7:02,12:19,12:45,2:53,3:34,3:45,5:28,5:33,6:57,7:15
21/02/2020,5:23,5:53,7:00,12:19,12:45,2:54,3:36,3:45,5:29,5:34,6:57,7:15
22/02/2020,5:21,5:51,6:58,12:19,12:45,2:55,3:37,4:00,5:31,5:36,6:59,7:30
23/02/2020,5:19,5:49,6:56,12:19,12:25,2:57,3:39,4:00,5:33,5:38,7:01,7:30
24/02/2020,5:17,5:47,6:54,12:19,12:45,2:58,3:41,4:00,5:35,5:40,7:03,7:30
25/02/2020,5:14,5:44,6:51,12:19,12:45,2:59,3:42,4:00,5:37,5:42,7:04,7:30
26/02/2020,5:12,5:42,6:49,12:18,12:45,3:01,3:44,4:00,5:38,5:43,7:05,7:30
27/02/2020,5:10,5:40,6:47,12:18,12:45,3:02,3:45,4:00,5:40,5:45,7:07,7:30
28/02/2020,5:08,5:38,6:45,12:18,12:45,3:03,3:47,4:00,5:42,5:47,7:09,7:30
01/03/2020,5:06,5:36,6:43,12:18,12:45,3:04,3:48,4:15,5:44,5:49,7:10,7:45
02/03/2020,5:04,5:34,6:41,12:18,12:25,3:06,3:50,4:15,5:45,5:50,7:11,7:45
03/03/2020,5:02,5:32,6:39,12:17,12:45,3:07,3:51,4:15,5:47,5:52,7:12,7:45
04/03/2020,4:59,5:29,6:36,12:17,12:45,3:08,3:53,4:15,5:49,5:54,7:14,7:45
05/03/2020,4:57,5:27,6:34,12:17,12:45,3:09,3:55,4:15,5:51,5:56,7:15,7:45
06/03/2020,4:55,5:25,6:32,12:17,12:45,3:10,3:56,4:15,5:52,5:57,7:16,7:45
07/03/2020,4:53,5:23,6:30,12:17,12:45,3:12,3:57,4:15,5:54,5:59,7:17,7:45
08/03/2020,4:51,5:21,6:28,12:16,12:45,3:13,3:59,4:15,5:56,6:01,7:19,7:45
09/03/2020,4:48,5:18,6:25,12:16,12:25,3:14,4:00,4:30,5:58,6:03,7:20,7:45
10/03/2020,4:46,5:16,6:23,12:16,12:45,3:15,4:02,4:30,5:59,6:04,7:21,7:45
11/03/2020,4:44,5:14,6:21,12:16,12:45,3:16,4:03,4:30,6:01,6:06,7:23,7:45
12/03/2020,4:42,5:12,6:19,12:15,12:45,3:17,4:05,4:30,6:03,6:08,7:25,7:45
13/03/2020,4:39,5:09,6:16,12:15,12:45,3:18,4:06,4:30,6:04,6:09,7:25,7:45
14/03/2020,4:37,5:07,6:14,12:15,12:45,3:20,4:08,4:30,6:06,6:11,7:27,7:45
15/03/2020,4:35,5:05,6:12,12:14,12:45,3:21,4:09,4:30,6:08,6:13,7:29,7:45
16/03/2020,4:33,5:03,6:10,12:14,12:25,3:22,4:10,4:30,6:10,6:15,7:31,7:45
17/03/2020,4:30,5:00,6:07,12:14,12:45,3:23,4:12,4:45,6:11,6:16,7:31,8:00
18/03/2020,4:28,4:58,6:05,12:14,12:45,3:24,4:13,4:45,6:13,6:18,7:33,8:00
19/03/2020,4:26,4:56,6:03,12:13,12:45,3:25,4:15,4:45,6:15,6:20,7:35,8:00
20/03/2020,4:25,4:55,6:01,12:13,12:45,3:26,4:16,4:45,6:16,6:21,7:36,8:00
21/03/2020,4:22,4:52,5:58,12:13,12:45,3:27,4:17,4:45,6:18,6:23,7:37,8:00
22/03/2020,4:21,4:51,5:56,12:12,12:45,3:28,4:19,4:45,6:20,6:25,7:39,8:00
23/03/2020,4:19,4:49,5:54,12:12,12:25,3:29,4:20,4:45,6:22,6:27,7:41,8:00
24/03/2020,4:16,4:46,5:51,12:12,12:45,3:30,4:21,4:45,6:23,6:28,7:42,8:00
25/03/2020,5:14,5:44,6:49,1:11,1:30,4:31,5:22,5:45,7:25,7:30,8:43,9:00
26/03/2020,5:13,5:43,6:47,1:11,1:30,4:32,5:24,5:45,7:27,7:32,8:45,9:00
27/03/2020,5:11,5:41,6:45,1:11,1:30,4:33,5:25,5:45,7:28,7:33,8:46,9:00
28/03/2020,5:09,5:39,6:42,1:11,1:30,4:34,5:26,5:45,7:30,7:35,8:48,9:00
29/03/2020,5:07,5:37,6:40,1:10,1:30,4:35,5:28,5:45,7:32,7:37,8:49,9:00
30/03/2020,5:05,5:35,6:38,1:10,1:15,4:36,5:29,5:45,7:33,7:38,8:50,9:00
31/03/2020,5:03,5:33,6:35,1:10,1:30,4:36,5:30,5:45,7:35,7:40,8:52,9:00
01/04/2020,5:01,5:31,6:33,1:09,1:30,4:37,5:31,6:00,7:37,7:42,8:54,9:15
02/04/2020,4:59,5:29,6:31,1:09,1:30,4:38,5:32,6:00,7:38,7:43,8:55,9:15
03/04/2020,4:57,5:27,6:29,1:09,1:30,4:39,5:34,6:00,7:40,7:45,8:56,9:15
04/04/2020,4:54,5:24,6:26,1:09,1:30,4:40,5:35,6:00,7:42,7:47,8:58,9:15
05/04/2020,4:52,5:22,6:24,1:08,1:30,4:41,5:36,6:00,7:43,7:48,8:59,9:15
06/04/2020,4:50,5:20,6:22,1:08,1:15,4:42,5:37,6:00,7:45,7:50,9:01,9:15
07/04/2020,4:48,5:18,6:20,1:08,1:30,4:43,5:38,6:00,7:47,7:52,9:03,9:15
08/04/2020,4:45,5:15,6:17,1:07,1:30,4:43,5:40,6:00,7:48,7:53,9:04,9:30
09/04/2020,4:43,5:13,6:15,1:07,1:30,4:44,5:41,6:00,7:50,7:55,9:05,9:30
10/04/2020,4:41,5:11,6:13,1:07,1:30,4:45,5:42,6:00,7:52,7:57,9:07,9:30
11/04/2020,4:39,5:09,6:11,1:07,1:30,4:46,5:43,6:00,7:53,7:58,9:08,9:30
12/04/2020,4:37,5:07,6:09,1:06,1:30,4:47,5:44,6:00,7:55,8:00,9:10,9:30
13/04/2020,4:35,5:05,6:07,1:06,1:15,4:47,5:45,6:00,7:57,8:02,9:12,9:30
14/04/2020,4:32,5:02,6:04,1:06,1:30,4:48,5:47,6:00,7:58,8:03,9:13,9:30
15/04/2020,4:30,5:00,6:02,1:06,1:30,4:49,5:48,6:15,8:00,8:05,9:15,9:45
16/04/2020,4:28,4:58,6:00,1:05,1:30,4:50,5:49,6:15,8:02,8:07,9:17,9:45
17/04/2020,4:26,4:56,5:58,1:05,1:30,4:51,5:50,6:15,8:03,8:08,9:17,9:45
18/04/2020,4:23,4:53,5:56,1:05,1:30,4:51,5:51,6:15,8:05,8:10,9:19,9:45
19/04/2020,4:21,4:51,5:54,1:05,1:30,4:52,5:52,6:15,8:07,8:12,9:21,9:45
20/04/2020,4:19,4:49,5:52,1:04,1:15,4:53,5:53,6:15,8:08,8:13,9:22,9:45
21/04/2020,4:16,4:46,5:50,1:04,1:30,4:54,5:54,6:15,8:10,8:15,9:24,9:45
22/04/2020,4:13,4:43,5:47,1:04,1:30,4:54,5:55,6:15,8:12,8:17,9:26,9:45
23/04/2020,4:11,4:41,5:45,1:04,1:30,4:55,5:56,6:30,8:13,8:18,9:26,9:45
24/04/2020,4:08,4:38,5:43,1:04,1:30,4:56,5:58,6:30,8:15,8:20,9:28,9:45
25/04/2020,4:06,4:36,5:41,1:03,1:30,4:56,5:59,6:30,8:17,8:22,9:30,9:45
26/04/2020,4:04,4:34,5:39,1:03,1:30,4:57,6:00,6:30,8:18,8:23,9:30,9:45
27/04/2020,4:01,4:31,5:37,1:03,1:15,4:58,6:01,6:30,8:20,8:25,9:32,9:45
28/04/2020,3:59,4:29,5:35,1:03,1:30,4:59,6:02,6:30,8:22,8:27,9:34,9:45
29/04/2020,3:57,4:27,5:33,1:03,1:30,4:59,6:03,6:30,8:23,8:28,9:34,9:45
30/04/2020,3:55,4:25,5:32,1:03,1:30,5:00,6:04,6:30,8:25,8:30,9:36,9:45
01/05/2020,3:52,4:22,5:30,1:03,1:30,5:01,6:05,6:30,8:27,8:32,9:38,10:00
02/05/2020,3:50,4:20,5:28,1:02,1:30,5:01,6:06,6:30,8:28,8:33,9:39,10:00
03/05/2020,3:47,4:17,5:26,1:02,1:30,5:02,6:07,6:30,8:30,8:35,9:41,10:00
04/05/2020,3:45,4:15,5:24,1:02,1:15,5:03,6:08,6:30,8:31,8:36,9:42,10:00
05/05/2020,3:42,4:12,5:22,1:02,1:30,5:03,6:09,6:30,8:33,8:38,9:44,10:00
06/05/2020,3:41,4:11,5:21,1:02,1:30,5:04,6:10,6:30,8:35,8:40,9:46,10:00
07/05/2020,3:38,4:08,5:19,1:02,1:30,5:04,6:11,6:30,8:36,8:41,9:47,10:00
08/05/2020,3:36,4:06,5:17,1:02,1:30,5:05,6:12,6:45,8:38,8:43,9:49,10:15
09/05/2020,3:33,4:03,5:15,1:02,1:30,5:06,6:13,6:45,8:39,8:44,9:50,10:15
10/05/2020,3:32,4:02,5:14,1:02,1:30,5:06,6:13,6:45,8:41,8:46,9:52,10:15
11/05/2020,3:29,3:59,5:12,1:02,1:15,5:07,6:14,6:45,8:43,8:48,9:54,10:15
12/05/2020,3:28,3:58,5:11,1:02,1:30,5:08,6:15,6:45,8:44,8:49,9:55,10:15
13/05/2020,3:25,3:55,5:09,1:02,1:30,5:08,6:16,6:45,8:46,8:51,9:56,10:15
14/05/2020,3:23,3:53,5:07,1:02,1:30,5:09,6:17,6:45,8:47,8:52,9:57,10:15
15/05/2020,3:21,3:51,5:06,1:02,1:30,5:09,6:18,6:45,8:49,8:54,9:59,10:45
16/05/2020,3:19,3:34,5:04,1:02,1:30,5:10,6:19,6:45,8:50,9:05,10:01,10:45
17/05/2020,3:17,3:32,5:03,1:02,1:30,5:10,6:20,6:45,8:52,9:07,10:03,10:45
18/05/2020,3:16,3:31,5:02,1:02,1:15,5:11,6:21,6:45,8:53,9:08,10:04,10:45
19/05/2020,3:13,3:28,5:00,1:02,1:30,5:12,6:21,6:45,8:55,9:10,10:07,10:45
20/05/2020,3:12,3:27,4:59,1:02,1:30,5:12,6:22,6:45,8:56,9:11,10:08,10:45
21/05/2020,3:10,3:25,4:58,1:02,1:30,5:13,6:23,6:45,8:57,9:12,10:09,10:45
22/05/2020,3:08,3:23,4:56,1:02,1:30,5:13,6:24,6:45,8:59,9:14,10:12,10:45
23/05/2020,3:06,3:21,4:55,1:02,1:30,5:14,6:25,6:45,9:00,9:15,10:13,10:45
24/05/2020,3:04,3:19,4:54,1:02,1:30,5:14,6:26,6:45,9:02,9:17,10:15,10:45
25/05/2020,3:02,3:17,4:53,1:02,1:15,5:15,6:26,6:45,9:03,9:18,10:17,11:00
26/05/2020,3:01,3:16,4:52,1:03,1:30,5:15,6:27,6:45,9:04,9:19,10:18,11:00
27/05/2020,2:59,3:14,4:51,1:03,1:30,5:16,6:28,6:45,9:05,9:20,10:19,11:00
28/05/2020,2:58,3:13,4:50,1:03,1:30,5:16,6:29,6:45,9:07,9:22,10:22,11:00
29/05/2020,2:56,3:11,4:49,1:03,1:30,5:17,6:29,6:45,9:08,9:23,10:23,11:00
30/05/2020,2:55,3:10,4:48,1:03,1:30,5:17,6:30,6:45,9:09,9:24,10:24,11:00
31/05/2020,2:53,3:08,4:47,1:03,1:30,5:18,6:31,6:45,9:10,9:25,10:26,11:00
01/06/2020,2:52,3:07,4:46,1:03,1:15,5:18,6:31,6:45,9:11,9:26,10:27,11:00
02/06/2020,2:50,3:05,4:45,1:03,1:30,5:19,6:32,6:45,9:12,9:27,10:29,11:00
03/06/2020,2:50,3:05,4:45,1:04,1:30,5:19,6:33,6:45,9:13,9:28,10:30,11:00
04/06/2020,2:48,3:03,4:44,1:04,1:30,5:20,6:33,6:45,9:14,9:29,10:31,11:00
05/06/2020,2:47,3:02,4:43,1:04,1:30,5:20,6:34,6:45,9:15,9:30,10:33,11:00
06/06/2020,2:46,3:01,4:43,1:04,1:30,5:21,6:34,7:00,9:16,9:31,10:34,11:00
07/06/2020,2:45,3:00,4:42,1:04,1:30,5:21,6:35,7:00,9:17,9:32,10:35,11:00
08/06/2020,2:44,2:59,4:42,1:05,1:15,5:21,6:35,7:00,9:18,9:33,10:36,11:00
09/06/2020,2:43,2:58,4:41,1:05,1:30,5:22,6:36,7:00,9:19,9:34,10:38,11:00
10/06/2020,2:42,2:57,4:41,1:05,1:30,5:22,6:36,7:00,9:19,9:34,10:38,11:00
11/06/2020,2:42,2:57,4:41,1:05,1:30,5:22,6:37,7:00,9:20,9:35,10:40,11:00
12/06/2020,2:40,2:55,4:40,1:05,1:30,5:23,6:37,7:00,9:21,9:36,10:41,11:00
13/06/2020,2:39,2:54,4:40,1:06,1:30,5:23,6:38,7:00,9:21,9:36,10:42,11:00
14/06/2020,2:39,2:54,4:40,1:06,1:30,5:23,6:38,7:00,9:22,9:37,10:43,11:00
15/06/2020,2:39,3:09,4:40,1:06,1:15,5:24,6:38,7:00,9:22,9:27,10:43,11:00
16/06/2020,2:39,3:09,4:40,1:06,1:30,5:24,6:39,7:00,9:23,9:28,10:43,11:00
17/06/2020,2:39,3:09,4:40,1:06,1:30,5:24,6:39,7:00,9:23,9:28,10:43,11:00
18/06/2020,2:39,3:09,4:40,1:07,1:30,5:25,6:39,7:00,9:24,9:29,10:43,11:00
19/06/2020,2:39,3:09,4:40,1:07,1:30,5:25,6:40,7:00,9:24,9:39,10:43,11:00
20/06/2020,2:40,3:10,4:40,1:07,1:30,5:25,6:40,7:00,9:24,9:29,10:43,11:00
21/06/2020,2:40,3:10,4:40,1:07,1:30,5:25,6:40,7:00,9:24,9:29,10:42,11:00
22/06/2020,2:40,3:10,4:40,1:08,1:15,5:25,6:40,7:00,9:25,9:30,10:42,11:00
23/06/2020,2:42,3:12,4:41,1:08,1:30,5:26,6:40,7:00,9:25,9:30,10:42,11:00
24/06/2020,2:42,3:12,4:41,1:08,1:30,5:26,6:41,7:00,9:25,9:30,10:41,11:00
25/06/2020,2:42,3:12,4:41,1:08,1:30,5:26,6:41,7:00,9:25,9:30,10:41,11:00
26/06/2020,2:44,3:14,4:42,1:08,1:30,5:26,6:41,7:00,9:25,9:30,10:41,11:00
27/06/2020,2:44,3:14,4:42,1:09,1:30,5:26,6:41,7:00,9:25,9:30,10:40,11:00
28/06/2020,2:46,3:16,4:43,1:09,1:30,5:26,6:41,7:00,9:25,9:30,10:40,11:00
29/06/2020,2:46,3:16,4:43,1:09,1:15,5:26,6:41,7:00,9:24,9:29,10:38,11:00
30/06/2020,2:47,3:17,4:44,1:09,1:30,5:26,6:41,7:00,9:24,9:29,10:37,11:00
01/07/2020,2:49,3:19,4:45,1:09,1:30,5:27,6:41,7:00,9:24,9:29,10:36,10:45
02/07/2020,2:50,3:20,4:45,1:10,1:30,5:27,6:41,7:00,9:23,9:28,10:35,10:45
03/07/2020,2:51,3:21,4:46,1:10,1:30,5:27,6:41,7:00,9:23,9:28,10:35,10:45
04/07/2020,2:53,3:23,4:47,1:10,1:30,5:26,6:40,7:00,9:23,9:28,10:34,10:45
05/07/2020,2:54,3:24,4:48,1:10,1:30,5:26,6:40,7:00,9:22,9:27,10:33,10:45
06/07/2020,2:54,3:24,4:48,1:10,1:15,5:26,6:40,7:00,9:22,9:27,10:33,10:45
07/07/2020,2:56,3:26,4:49,1:10,1:30,5:26,6:40,7:00,9:21,9:26,10:31,10:45
08/07/2020,2:57,3:27,4:50,1:11,1:30,5:26,6:40,7:00,9:20,9:25,10:30,10:45
09/07/2020,2:59,3:29,4:51,1:11,1:30,5:26,6:39,7:00,9:20,9:25,10:30,10:45
10/07/2020,3:00,3:30,4:52,1:11,1:30,5:26,6:39,7:00,9:19,9:24,10:28,10:45
11/07/2020,3:01,3:31,4:53,1:11,1:30,5:26,6:39,7:00,9:18,9:23,10:27,10:45
12/07/2020,3:03,3:33,4:54,1:11,1:30,5:26,6:38,7:00,9:17,9:22,10:26,10:45
13/07/2020,3:05,3:35,4:56,1:11,1:15,5:25,6:38,7:00,9:16,9:21,10:24,10:45
14/07/2020,3:07,3:37,4:57,1:11,1:30,5:25,6:37,7:00,9:15,9:20,10:23,10:45
15/07/2020,3:08,3:38,4:58,1:12,1:30,5:25,6:37,7:00,9:14,9:19,10:22,10:45
16/07/2020,3:09,3:39,4:59,1:12,1:30,5:25,6:36,7:00,9:13,9:18,10:20,10:45
17/07/2020,3:11,3:41,5:00,1:12,1:30,5:24,6:36,7:00,9:12,9:17,10:19,10:30
18/07/2020,3:12,3:42,5:01,1:12,1:30,5:24,6:35,7:00,9:11,9:16,10:18,10:30
19/07/2020,3:15,3:45,5:03,1:12,1:30,5:23,6:35,7:00,9:10,9:15,10:16,10:30
20/07/2020,3:16,3:46,5:04,1:12,1:15,5:23,6:34,7:00,9:09,9:14,10:15,10:30
21/07/2020,3:17,3:47,5:05,1:12,1:30,5:23,6:33,7:00,9:08,9:13,10:14,10:30
22/07/2020,3:20,3:50,5:07,1:12,1:30,5:22,6:33,7:00,9:06,9:11,10:11,10:30
23/07/2020,3:21,3:51,5:08,1:12,1:30,5:22,6:32,7:00,9:05,9:10,10:10,10:30
24/07/2020,3:23,3:53,5:09,1:12,1:30,5:21,6:31,7:00,9:04,9:09,10:09,10:30
25/07/2020,3:25,3:55,5:11,1:12,1:30,5:21,6:30,6:45,9:02,9:07,10:06,10:15
26/07/2020,3:27,3:57,5:12,1:12,1:30,5:20,6:29,6:45,9:01,9:06,10:05,10:15
27/07/2020,3:29,3:59,5:14,1:12,1:15,5:20,6:29,6:45,8:59,9:04,10:03,10:15
28/07/2020,3:31,4:01,5:15,1:12,1:30,5:19,6:28,6:45,8:58,9:03,10:01,10:15
29/07/2020,3:33,4:03,5:17,1:12,1:30,5:18,6:27,6:45,8:56,9:01,9:59,10:15
30/07/2020,3:35,4:05,5:18,1:12,1:30,5:18,6:26,6:45,8:55,9:00,9:58,10:15
31/07/2020,3:37,4:07,5:20,1:12,1:30,5:17,6:25,6:45,8:53,8:58,9:56,10:15
01/08/2020,3:39,4:09,5:21,1:12,1:30,5:16,6:24,6:45,8:52,8:57,9:56,10:15
02/08/2020,3:41,4:11,5:23,1:12,1:30,5:16,6:23,6:45,8:50,8:55,9:54,10:15
03/08/2020,3:43,4:13,5:24,1:12,1:15,5:15,6:22,6:45,8:48,8:53,9:52,10:15
04/08/2020,3:45,4:15,5:26,1:12,1:30,5:14,6:21,6:45,8:47,8:52,9:51,10:15
05/08/2020,3:47,4:17,5:27,1:12,1:30,5:13,6:20,6:45,8:45,8:50,9:49,10:15
06/08/2020,3:49,4:19,5:29,1:11,1:30,5:13,6:18,6:45,8:43,8:48,9:48,10:15
07/08/2020,3:50,4:20,5:30,1:11,1:30,5:12,6:17,6:45,8:41,8:46,9:46,10:15
08/08/2020,3:53,4:23,5:32,1:11,1:30,5:11,6:16,6:30,8:40,8:45,9:45,10:00
09/08/2020,3:54,4:24,5:33,1:11,1:30,5:10,6:15,6:30,8:38,8:43,9:43,10:00
10/08/2020,3:56,4:26,5:35,1:11,1:15,5:09,6:14,6:30,8:36,8:41,9:41,10:00
11/08/2020,3:58,4:28,5:36,1:11,1:30,5:08,6:12,6:30,8:34,8:39,9:40,10:00
12/08/2020,4:00,4:30,5:38,1:11,1:30,5:07,6:11,6:30,8:32,8:37,9:38,10:00
13/08/2020,4:02,4:32,5:40,1:10,1:30,5:06,6:10,6:30,8:30,8:35,9:36,10:00
14/08/2020,4:04,4:34,5:41,1:10,1:30,5:05,6:08,6:30,8:28,8:33,9:34,10:00
15/08/2020,4:06,4:36,5:43,1:10,1:30,5:04,6:07,6:30,8:26,8:31,9:32,10:00
16/08/2020,4:07,4:37,5:44,1:10,1:30,5:03,6:06,6:30,8:24,8:29,9:31,9:45
17/08/2020,4:10,4:40,5:46,1:10,1:15,5:02,6:04,6:30,8:22,8:27,9:29,9:45
18/08/2020,4:12,4:42,5:48,1:09,1:30,5:01,6:03,6:30,8:20,8:25,9:27,9:45
19/08/2020,4:13,4:43,5:49,1:09,1:30,5:00,6:01,6:30,8:18,8:23,9:25,9:45
20/08/2020,4:16,4:46,5:51,1:09,1:30,4:59,6:00,6:30,8:16,8:21,9:23,9:45
21/08/2020,4:17,4:47,5:52,1:09,1:30,4:58,5:58,6:30,8:14,8:19,9:22,9:45
22/08/2020,4:19,4:49,5:54,1:08,1:30,4:56,5:57,6:30,8:12,8:17,9:20,9:45
23/08/2020,4:22,4:52,5:56,1:08,1:30,4:55,5:55,6:30,8:10,8:15,9:18,9:45
24/08/2020,4:23,4:53,5:57,1:08,1:15,4:54,5:54,6:15,8:08,8:13,9:16,9:30
25/08/2020,4:25,4:55,5:59,1:08,1:30,4:53,5:52,6:15,8:05,8:10,9:14,9:30
26/08/2020,4:27,4:57,6:00,1:07,1:30,4:52,5:51,6:15,8:03,8:08,9:12,9:30
27/08/2020,4:29,4:59,6:02,1:07,1:30,4:50,5:49,6:15,8:01,8:06,9:10,9:30
28/08/2020,4:30,5:00,6:03,1:07,1:30,4:49,5:47,6:15,7:59,8:04,9:08,9:30
29/08/2020,4:33,5:03,6:05,1:06,1:30,4:48,5:46,6:15,7:57,8:02,9:07,9:30
30/08/2020,4:35,5:05,6:07,1:06,1:30,4:46,5:44,6:15,7:55,8:00,9:05,9:30
31/08/2020,4:36,5:06,6:08,1:06,1:15,4:45,5:42,6:15,7:52,7:57,9:02,9:30
01/09/2020,4:38,5:08,6:10,1:06,1:30,4:44,5:41,6:00,7:50,7:55,9:01,9:15
02/09/2020,4:39,5:09,6:11,1:05,1:30,4:42,5:39,6:00,7:48,7:53,8:59,9:15
03/09/2020,4:41,5:11,6:13,1:05,1:30,4:41,5:37,6:00,7:46,7:51,8:57,9:15
04/09/2020,4:43,5:13,6:15,1:05,1:30,4:39,5:35,6:00,7:43,7:48,8:55,9:15
05/09/2020,4:44,5:14,6:16,1:04,1:30,4:38,5:34,6:00,7:41,7:46,8:53,9:15
06/09/2020,4:46,5:16,6:18,1:04,1:30,4:36,5:32,6:00,7:39,7:44,8:51,9:15
07/09/2020,4:47,5:17,6:19,1:04,1:15,4:35,5:30,6:00,7:37,7:42,8:50,9:15
08/09/2020,4:49,5:19,6:21,1:03,1:30,4:34,5:28,6:00,7:34,7:39,8:47,9:15
09/09/2020,4:51,5:21,6:23,1:03,1:30,4:32,5:26,5:45,7:32,7:37,8:45,9:00
10/09/2020,4:52,5:22,6:24,1:03,1:30,4:31,5:24,5:45,7:30,7:35,8:43,9:00
11/09/2020,4:54,5:24,6:26,1:02,1:30,4:29,5:23,5:45,7:27,7:32,8:41,9:00
12/09/2020,4:55,5:25,6:27,1:02,1:30,4:27,5:21,5:45,7:25,7:30,8:39,9:00
13/09/2020,4:57,5:27,6:29,1:01,1:30,4:26,5:19,5:45,7:23,7:28,8:37,9:00
14/09/2020,4:59,5:29,6:31,1:01,1:15,4:24,5:17,5:45,7:21,7:26,8:35,9:00
15/09/2020,5:00,5:30,6:32,1:01,1:30,4:23,5:15,5:45,7:18,7:23,8:33,9:00
16/09/2020,5:03,5:33,6:34,1:00,1:30,4:21,5:13,5:30,7:16,7:21,8:31,8:45
17/09/2020,5:04,5:34,6:35,1:00,1:30,4:20,5:11,5:30,7:14,7:19,8:29,8:45
18/09/2020,5:06,5:36,6:37,1:00,1:30,4:18,5:09,5:30,7:11,7:16,8:26,8:45
19/09/2020,5:09,5:39,6:39,12:59,1:30,4:16,5:07,5:30,7:09,7:14,8:24,8:45
20/09/2020,5:10,5:40,6:40,12:59,1:30,4:15,5:05,5:30,7:07,7:12,8:22,8:45
21/09/2020,5:12,5:42,6:42,12:59,1:15,4:13,5:04,5:30,7:04,7:09,8:20,8:45
22/09/2020,5:14,5:44,6:43,12:58,1:30,4:11,5:02,5:30,7:02,7:07,8:18,8:45
23/09/2020,5:16,5:46,6:45,12:58,1:30,4:10,5:00,5:15,7:00,7:05,8:16,8:30
24/09/2020,5:18,5:48,6:47,12:58,1:30,4:08,4:58,5:15,6:58,7:03,8:14,8:30
25/09/2020,5:20,5:50,6:48,12:57,1:30,4:06,4:56,5:15,6:55,7:00,8:12,8:30
26/09/2020,5:22,5:52,6:50,12:57,1:30,4:05,4:54,5:15,6:53,6:58,8:10,8:30
27/09/2020,5:23,5:53,6:51,12:57,1:30,4:03,4:52,5:15,6:51,6:56,8:08,8:30
28/09/2020,5:26,5:56,6:53,12:56,1:15,4:01,4:50,5:15,6:48,6:53,8:05,8:30
29/09/2020,5:28,5:58,6:55,12:56,1:30,4:00,4:48,5:15,6:46,6:51,8:03,8:30
30/09/2020,5:29,5:59,6:56,12:56,1:30,3:58,4:46,5:15,6:44,6:49,8:01,8:30
01/10/2020,5:30,6:00,6:58,12:55,1:30,3:56,4:44,5:00,6:42,6:47,8:00,8:15
02/10/2020,5:32,6:02,7:00,12:55,1:30,3:55,4:42,5:00,6:39,6:44,7:57,8:15
03/10/2020,5:33,6:03,7:01,12:55,1:30,3:53,4:40,5:00,6:37,6:42,7:56,8:15
04/10/2020,5:35,6:05,7:03,12:54,1:30,3:51,4:38,5:00,6:35,6:40,7:54,8:15
05/10/2020,5:35,6:05,7:04,12:54,1:15,3:50,4:36,5:00,6:32,6:37,7:51,8:15
06/10/2020,5:37,6:07,7:06,12:54,1:30,3:48,4:34,5:00,6:30,6:35,7:49,8:15
07/10/2020,5:39,6:09,7:08,12:53,1:30,3:46,4:32,5:00,6:28,6:33,7:49,8:15
08/10/2020,5:39,6:09,7:09,12:53,1:30,3:45,4:30,5:00,6:26,6:31,7:47,8:15
09/10/2020,5:41,6:11,7:11,12:53,1:30,3:43,4:28,4:45,6:24,6:29,7:45,8:00
10/10/2020,5:43,6:13,7:13,12:53,1:30,3:41,4:26,4:45,6:21,6:26,7:42,8:00
11/10/2020,5:43,6:13,7:14,12:52,1:30,3:39,4:24,4:45,6:19,6:24,7:40,8:00
12/10/2020,5:45,6:15,7:16,12:52,1:15,3:38,4:22,4:45,6:17,6:22,7:38,8:00
13/10/2020,5:47,6:17,7:18,12:52,1:30,3:36,4:20,4:45,6:15,6:20,7:38,8:00
14/10/2020,5:48,6:18,7:20,12:52,1:30,3:34,4:18,4:45,6:13,6:18,7:36,8:00
15/10/2020,5:49,6:19,7:21,12:51,1:30,3:33,4:16,4:45,6:11,6:16,7:34,8:00
16/10/2020,5:51,6:21,7:23,12:51,1:30,3:31,4:14,4:45,6:08,6:13,7:31,8:00
17/10/2020,5:52,6:22,7:25,12:51,1:30,3:30,4:12,4:30,6:06,6:11,7:29,7:45
18/10/2020,5:53,6:23,7:26,12:51,1:30,3:28,4:10,4:30,6:04,6:09,7:27,7:45
19/10/2020,5:55,6:25,7:28,12:50,1:15,3:26,4:08,4:30,6:02,6:07,7:25,7:45
20/10/2020,5:57,6:27,7:30,12:50,1:30,3:25,4:06,4:30,6:00,6:05,7:23,7:45
21/10/2020,5:58,6:28,7:32,12:50,1:30,3:23,4:05,4:30,5:58,6:03,7:23,7:45
22/10/2020,5:59,6:29,7:33,12:50,1:30,3:21,4:03,4:30,5:56,6:01,7:21,7:45
23/10/2020,6:00,6:30,7:35,12:50,1:30,3:20,4:01,4:15,5:54,5:59,7:19,7:45
24/10/2020,6:02,6:32,7:37,12:50,1:30,3:18,3:59,4:15,5:52,5:57,7:17,7:45
25/10/2020,6:03,6:33,7:38,12:50,1:30,3:17,3:57,4:15,5:50,5:55,7:17,7:45
26/10/2020,6:04,6:34,7:40,12:49,1:15,3:15,3:55,4:15,5:48,5:53,7:15,7:45
27/10/2020,6:06,6:36,7:42,12:49,1:30,3:14,3:54,4:15,5:46,5:51,7:13,7:45
28/10/2020,5:08,5:38,6:44,11:49,12:45,2:12,2:52,3:00,4:44,4:49,6:11,7:15
29/10/2020,5:08,5:38,6:45,11:49,12:45,2:11,2:50,3:00,4:42,4:47,6:09,7:15
30/10/2020,5:10,5:40,6:47,11:49,12:45,2:09,2:48,3:00,4:40,4:45,6:07,7:15
31/10/2020,5:12,5:42,6:49,11:49,12:45,2:08,2:47,3:00,4:39,4:44,6:06,7:15
01/11/2020,5:14,5:44,6:51,11:49,12:45,2:06,2:45,3:00,4:37,4:42,6:05,7:15
02/11/2020,5:16,5:46,6:53,11:49,12:25,2:05,2:43,3:00,4:35,4:40,6:03,7:15
03/11/2020,5:17,5:47,6:54,11:49,12:45,2:04,2:41,3:00,4:33,4:38,6:02,7:15
04/11/2020,5:18,5:48,6:56,11:49,12:45,2:02,2:40,3:00,4:31,4:36,6:00,7:15
05/11/2020,5:20,5:50,6:58,11:49,12:45,2:01,2:38,3:00,4:30,4:35,6:00,7:15
06/11/2020,5:22,5:52,7:00,11:49,12:45,2:00,2:37,3:00,4:28,4:33,5:58,7:15
07/11/2020,5:22,5:52,7:01,11:49,12:45,1:58,2:35,3:00,4:26,4:31,5:57,7:15
08/11/2020,5:24,5:54,7:03,11:49,12:45,1:57,2:34,3:00,4:25,4:30,5:56,7:15
09/11/2020,5:26,5:56,7:05,11:49,12:25,1:56,2:32,3:00,4:23,4:28,5:55,7:15
10/11/2020,5:27,5:57,7:07,11:49,12:45,1:55,2:31,3:00,4:22,4:27,5:54,7:15
11/11/2020,5:28,5:58,7:08,11:50,12:45,1:53,2:29,2:45,4:20,4:25,5:52,7:15
12/11/2020,5:30,6:00,7:10,11:50,12:45,1:52,2:28,2:45,4:19,4:24,5:51,7:15
13/11/2020,5:31,6:01,7:12,11:50,12:45,1:51,2:27,2:45,4:17,4:22,5:50,7:15
14/11/2020,5:33,6:03,7:14,11:50,12:45,1:50,2:25,2:45,4:16,4:21,5:49,7:15
15/11/2020,5:34,6:04,7:15,11:50,12:45,1:49,2:24,2:45,4:14,4:19,5:47,7:15
16/11/2020,5:35,6:05,7:17,11:50,12:25,1:48,2:23,2:45,4:13,4:18,5:46,7:15
17/11/2020,5:37,6:07,7:19,11:50,12:45,1:47,2:21,2:45,4:12,4:17,5:46,7:15
18/11/2020,5:38,6:08,7:20,11:51,12:45,1:46,2:20,2:45,4:10,4:15,5:44,7:15
19/11/2020,5:40,6:10,7:22,11:51,12:45,1:45,2:19,2:45,4:09,4:14,5:43,7:15
20/11/2020,5:42,6:12,7:24,11:51,12:45,1:44,2:18,2:45,4:08,4:13,5:42,7:15
21/11/2020,5:43,6:13,7:25,11:51,12:45,1:43,2:17,2:30,4:07,4:12,5:42,7:15
22/11/2020,5:45,6:15,7:27,11:52,12:45,1:43,2:16,2:30,4:06,4:11,5:41,7:15
23/11/2020,5:47,6:17,7:29,11:52,12:25,1:42,2:15,2:30,4:05,4:10,5:40,7:15
24/11/2020,5:48,6:18,7:30,11:52,12:45,1:41,2:14,2:30,4:04,4:09,5:39,7:15
25/11/2020,5:50,6:20,7:32,11:52,12:45,1:41,2:13,2:30,4:03,4:08,5:39,7:15
26/11/2020,5:51,6:21,7:33,11:53,12:45,1:40,2:12,2:30,4:02,4:07,5:38,7:15
27/11/2020,5:53,6:23,7:35,11:53,12:45,1:39,2:12,2:30,4:01,4:06,5:37,7:15
28/11/2020,5:54,6:24,7:36,11:53,12:45,1:39,2:11,2:30,4:00,4:05,5:36,7:15
29/11/2020,5:56,6:26,7:38,11:54,12:45,1:38,2:10,2:30,3:59,4:04,5:35,7:15
30/11/2020,5:57,6:27,7:39,11:54,12:25,1:38,2:09,2:30,3:59,4:04,5:36,7:15
01/12/2020,5:59,6:29,7:41,11:55,12:45,1:37,2:09,2:30,3:58,4:03,5:35,7:15
02/12/2020,6:00,6:30,7:42,11:55,12:45,1:37,2:08,2:30,3:57,4:02,5:34,7:15
03/12/2020,6:01,6:31,7:43,11:55,12:45,1:37,2:08,2:30,3:57,4:02,5:34,7:15
04/12/2020,6:03,6:33,7:45,11:56,12:45,1:36,2:07,2:30,3:56,4:01,5:33,7:15
05/12/2020,6:04,6:34,7:46,11:56,12:45,1:36,2:07,2:30,3:56,4:01,5:33,7:15
06/12/2020,6:05,6:35,7:47,11:57,12:45,1:36,2:07,2:30,3:56,4:01,5:33,7:15
07/12/2020,6:06,6:36,7:48,11:57,12:25,1:36,2:06,2:30,3:55,4:00,5:32,7:15
08/12/2020,6:08,6:38,7:50,11:57,12:45,1:36,2:06,2:30,3:55,4:00,5:32,7:15
09/12/2020,6:09,6:39,7:51,11:58,12:45,1:35,2:06,2:30,3:55,4:00,5:32,7:15
10/12/2020,6:10,6:40,7:52,11:58,12:45,1:36,2:06,2:30,3:55,4:00,5:32,7:15
11/12/2020,6:11,6:41,7:53,11:59,12:45,1:36,2:06,2:30,3:54,3:59,5:31,7:15
12/12/2020,6:12,6:42,7:54,11:59,12:45,1:36,2:06,2:30,3:54,3:59,5:31,7:15
13/12/2020,6:13,6:43,7:55,12:00,12:45,1:36,2:06,2:30,3:54,3:59,5:31,7:15
14/12/2020,6:14,6:44,7:56,12:00,12:25,1:36,2:06,2:30,3:54,3:59,5:31,7:15
15/12/2020,6:15,6:45,7:57,12:01,12:45,1:36,2:06,2:30,3:55,4:00,5:32,7:15
16/12/2020,6:16,6:46,7:57,12:01,12:45,1:36,2:06,2:30,3:55,4:00,5:32,7:15
17/12/2020,6:17,6:47,7:58,12:02,12:45,1:37,2:07,2:30,3:55,4:00,5:32,7:15
18/12/2020,6:18,6:48,7:59,12:02,12:45,1:37,2:07,2:30,3:55,4:00,5:32,7:15
19/12/2020,6:19,6:49,8:00,12:03,12:45,1:37,2:07,2:30,3:56,4:01,5:33,7:15
20/12/2020,6:20,6:50,8:00,12:03,12:45,1:38,2:08,2:30,3:56,4:01,5:33,7:15
21/12/2020,6:21,6:51,8:01,12:04,12:25,1:38,2:08,2:30,3:56,4:01,5:33,7:15
22/12/2020,6:21,6:51,8:01,12:04,12:45,1:39,2:09,2:30,3:57,4:02,5:34,7:15
23/12/2020,6:22,6:52,8:02,12:05,12:45,1:39,2:09,2:30,3:58,4:03,5:35,7:15
24/12/2020,6:22,6:52,8:02,12:05,12:45,1:40,2:10,2:30,3:58,4:03,5:35,7:15
25/12/2020,6:22,6:52,8:02,12:06,12:45,1:40,2:10,2:30,3:59,4:04,5:36,7:15
26/12/2020,6:25,6:55,8:03,12:06,12:45,1:41,2:11,2:30,4:00,4:05,5:37,7:15
27/12/2020,6:25,6:55,8:03,12:07,12:45,1:42,2:12,2:30,4:00,4:05,5:37,7:15
28/12/2020,6:25,6:55,8:03,12:07,12:25,1:43,2:13,2:30,4:01,4:06,5:38,7:15
29/12/2020,6:26,6:56,8:03,12:08,12:45,1:43,2:13,2:30,4:02,4:07,5:39,7:15
30/12/2020,6:26,6:56,8:03,12:08,12:45,1:44,2:14,2:30,4:03,4:08,5:40,7:15
31/12/2020,6:26,6:56,8:03,12:08,12:45,1:45,2:15,2:30,4:04,4:09,5:41,7:15
```

Comment: What do you mean you want users to update a line of it? As in the user should be able to change the line in their browser and then save it back it the CSV?

Comment: Yes I want to show this data in a table and give user options to edit any date or time and whenever he changes data csv file gets update

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs to retrieve or modify/update data in react

use this cmd

> npm i xlsx --save

Answer (score 0):

You can use d3 for reading CSV file like this:

```
   import {csv} from 'd3'
   
   
   csv('you file path').then(data=>{
           
          // csv data will be in the data variable
      })
```

Or you can check this answer:
-[React: import csv file and parse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53421129/12042686)