# Cannot fetch .csv data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I'm trying to fetch .csv data in react, however it returns as it below. I'm not sure why does it happen.

```
["<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵  <head>↵    <met…tatic/js/main.chunk.js"></script></body>↵</html>↵"]
```

**My code to fetch data.**

```
 async function getDummyData (){
      const URL = '../MockData/dummyData.csv';
      let data = await fetch(URL);
      data = await data.text();
      let dummyData = CSV.split('\r\n');
    }
    getDummyData();
```

However, code works as it should be on Vanilla JS and returns data of 100 paragraphs.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416529/react-import-csv-file-and-parse

Comment: The URL you have points to an HTML document (it looks like the bootstrap HTML document that loads your React application). Likely this is a server configuration issue.